# Child Div not respecting Overflow hidden In Safari

Tags: jquery, html, css

On below Fiddle, There is a pagination, when you will hover the pagination a circle will animate up but, In safari the image inside that circle is not respecting overflow hidden, In other browsers its working fine..

In any solution, Image needs to be centered vertically...

**Fiddle:-**

http://jsfiddle.net/w5uhet4x/

**html**

```
<div class="slideContainer vidopia slide-row">  
<div class="article_pagination2">
<div class="back_arrow2 arrow-disable"><a title="Prev" href="javascript:void(0);"><strong>Prev</strong></a></div>
<ul>
<li>
<div onclick="location.href='http://www0.bhaskar.com/news-ht/SPO-IPL-OFIPL-introducing-all-the-teams-of-indian-premier-league-8-4957058-PHO.html?seq=1'" class="pagination_no2"><span title="Slide 1" class="pg_number2 active">1</span>
<figure class="article_image2"><span class="image_inner"><img src="http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/thumbnail/70x70/web2images/www.bhaskar.com/2015/04/07/players_1428406480.jpg"></span></figure>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div onclick="location.href='http://www0.bhaskar.com/news-ht/SPO-IPL-OFIPL-introducing-all-the-teams-of-indian-premier-league-8-4957058-PHO.html?seq=2'" class="pagination_no2"><span title="Slide 2" class="pg_number2 ">2</span>
<figure class="article_image2"><span class="image_inner"><img src="http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/thumbnail/70x70/web2images/www.bhaskar.com/2015/04/07/dhoni_1428406477.jpg"></span></figure>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div onclick="location.href='http://www0.bhaskar.com/news-ht/SPO-IPL-OFIPL-introducing-all-the-teams-of-indian-premier-league-8-4957058-PHO.html?seq=3'" class="pagination_no2"><span title="Slide 3" class="pg_number2 ">3</span>
<figure class="article_image2"><span class="image_inner"><img src="http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/thumbnail/70x70/web2images/www.bhaskar.com/2015/04/07/bailey_1428406477.jpg"></span></figure>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div onclick="location.href='http://www0.bhaskar.com/news-ht/SPO-IPL-OFIPL-introducing-all-the-teams-of-indian-premier-league-8-4957058-PHO.html?seq=4'" class="pagination_no2"><span title="Slide 4" class="pg_number2 ">4</span>
<figure class="article_image2"><span class="image_inner"><img src="http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/thumbnail/70x70/web2images/www.bhaskar.com/2015/04/07/gautam_1428406478.jpg"></span></figure>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div onclick="location.href='http://www0.bhaskar.com/news-ht/SPO-IPL-OFIPL-introducing-all-the-teams-of-indian-premier-league-8-4957058-PHO.html?seq=5'" class="pagination_no2"><span title="Slide 5" class="pg_number2 ">5</span>
<figure class="article_image2"><span class="image_inner"><img src="http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/thumbnail/70x70/web2images/www.bhaskar.com/2015/04/07/rohit-1_1428406482.jpg"></span></figure>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div onclick="location.href='http://www0.bhaskar.com/news-ht/SPO-IPL-OFIPL-introducing-all-the-teams-of-indian-premier-league-8-4957058-PHO.html?seq=6'" class="pagination_no2"><span title="Slide 6" class="pg_number2 ">6</span>
<figure class="article_image2"><span class="image_inner"><img src="http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/thumbnail/70x70/web2images/www.bhaskar.com/2015/04/07/watson_1428406488.jpg"></span></figure>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div onclick="location.href='http://www0.bhaskar.com/news-ht/SPO-IPL-OFIPL-introducing-all-the-teams-of-indian-premier-league-8-4957058-PHO.html?seq=7'" class="pagination_no2"><span title="Slide 7" class="pg_number2 ">7</span>
<figure class="article_image2"><span class="image_inner"><img src="http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/thumbnail/70x70/web2images/www.bhaskar.com/2015/04/07/virat-1_1428406484.jpg"></span></figure>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div onclick="location.href='http://www0.bhaskar.com/news-ht/SPO-IPL-OFIPL-introducing-all-the-teams-of-indian-premier-league-8-4957058-PHO.html?seq=8'" class="pagination_no2"><span title="Slide 8" class="pg_number2 ">8</span>
<figure class="article_image2"><span class="image_inner"><img src="http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/thumbnail/70x70/web2images/www.bhaskar.com/2015/04/07/warner_1428406486.jpg"></span></figure>
</div>
</li>
</ul> 
<div class="next_arrow2 "><a title="Next" href="http://www0.bhaskar.com/news-ht/SPO-IPL-OFIPL-introducing-all-the-teams-of-indian-premier-league-8-4957058-PHO.html?seq=2"><strong>Next</strong></a></div>
</div>                      
</div>
```

**Css**

```
.article_slide2 {
    font: 25px/20px impact, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #0065bd;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.article_pagination2 {
    width: 680px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 10px 0;
    position: relative;
}
.article_pagination2:after {
    content: "";
    width: 94%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #0065bd;
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left: 22px;
    top: 17px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.article_pagination2 ul {
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 590px;
    font-size: 0px;
}
.article_pagination2 li {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 2;
    margin: 0 4px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.article_pagination2 li .pg_number2 {
    width: 33px;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    height: 33px;
    float: left; /*display:table-cell; */
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #0065bd;
    border: 2px solid #0065bd;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
    font-family: arial !important;
}
.article_pagination2 li .pg_number2:hover, .article_pagination2 li .pg_number2.active {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    transform: scale(1.15);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.15);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
    z-index: 2;
    color: #0065BD;
    border: 2px solid #0065BD;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
}
.article_pagination2 li:hover .article_image2 {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    top: -85px;
    top: -82px\9;
}
.article_pagination2 li .article_image2 {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 2px solid #0065bd;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left: -19px;
    transition: all .5s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 0;
}
.article_pagination2 li .image_inner {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
.article_pagination2 li .article_image2 img {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    top: 0;
}
.article_pagination2 li .article_image2:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 7px solid transparent;
    border-left: 7px solid transparent;
    border-top: 7px solid #0065bd;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 9;
    margin-left: -6px;
}
.article_pagination2 .back_arrow2 a, .article_pagination2 .next_arrow2 a {
    display: block;
    color: #333;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 34px;
    height: 46px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.article_pagination2 .back_arrow2 {
    background: url(http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/dainikbhaskar2010/images/pagination/ie_back_page_aro_2.png) no-repeat #fff;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    float: left;
    overflow: visible;
    background-size: 100%;
    margin-right: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.article_pagination2 .back_arrow2.arrow-disable {
    background: url(http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/dainikbhaskar2010/images/pagination/ie_back_page_aro_2_disable.png) no-repeat #fff;
}
.article_pagination2 .next_arrow2 {
    background: url(http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/dainikbhaskar2010/images/pagination/ie_next_page_aro_2.png) no-repeat #fff;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
    float: right;
    overflow: visible;
    margin-left: 5px;
    background-size: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.article_pagination2 .next_arrow2.arrow-disable {
    background: url(http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/dainikbhaskar2010/images/pagination/ie_next_page_aro_2_disable.png) no-repeat #fff;
}
.article_pagination2 .arrow-disable a {
    cursor: default;
}
.article_pagination2 .next_arrow2 strong, .article_pagination2 .back_arrow2 strong {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    left: 3px
}
.article_pagination2 .arrow-disable strong {
    color: #aeaeae;
}
.slideContainer.slide-row {
    height: 62px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a [Safari bug](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77572), it doesn't seem to like `position: relative;` on `.article_pagination2 li .image_inner` and `position: absolute;` on `.article_pagination2 li .article_image2 img`. If you remove `position` from these two selectors the issue disappears. This means that the centering of the `img` needs to be handled in a different way (as absolute positioning cannot be used), so I have added an extra pseudo element with `display: inline-block;`, `height: 100%;` and `vertical-align: middle;` to allow the `img` to be vertically aligned to the center of `.article_image2`.

- Remove `position: relative;` from `.article_pagination2 li .image_inner`
- Add `.article_pagination2 li .image_inner:after` with styles to allow for the image to vertically align
- Remove all styles relating to `absolute` positioning from `.article_pagination2 li .article_image2 img`
- Add `vertical-align: middle;` to `.article_pagination2 li .article_image2 img`

```css
.slideContainer {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.article_slide2 {
  font: 25px/20px impact, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #0065bd;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.article_pagination2 {
  width: 680px;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.article_pagination2:after {
  content: "";
  width: 94%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #0065bd;
  float: left;
  position: absolute;
  left: 22px;
  top: 17px;
  z-index: 0;
}
.article_pagination2 ul {
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 590px;
  font-size: 0px;
}
.article_pagination2 li {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.article_pagination2 li .pg_number2 {
  width: 33px;
  line-height: 33px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  height: 33px;
  float: left;
  /*display:table-cell; */
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #0065bd;
  border: 2px solid #0065bd;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  font-family: arial !important;
}
.article_pagination2 li .pg_number2:hover,
.article_pagination2 li .pg_number2.active {
  background: #FFFFFF;
  transform: scale(1.15);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.15);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
  z-index: 2;
  color: #0065BD;
  border: 2px solid #0065BD;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.article_pagination2 li:hover .article_image2 {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  top: -85px;
  top: -82px\9;
}
.article_pagination2 li .article_image2 {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 2px solid #0065bd;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: -19px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0;
}
.article_pagination2 li .image_inner {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
  /*position: relative; Remove*/
} 
/*Add*/
.article_pagination2 li .image_inner:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
}
.article_pagination2 li .article_image2 img {
  /*bottom: 0; Remove*/
  /*left: 0; Remove*/
  /*margin: auto; Remove*/
  /*position: absolute; Remove*/
  /*right: 0; Remove*/
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle; /*Add*/
  /*top: 0; Remove*/
}
.article_pagination2 li .article_image2:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 7px solid transparent;
  border-left: 7px solid transparent;
  border-top: 7px solid #0065bd;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -8px;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 9;
  margin-left: -6px;
}
.article_pagination2 .back_arrow2 a,
.article_pagination2 .next_arrow2 a {
  display: block;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  width: 34px;
  height: 46px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.article_pagination2 .back_arrow2 {
  background: url(http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/dainikbhaskar2010/images/pagination/ie_back_page_aro_2.png) no-repeat #fff;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  float: left;
  overflow: visible;
  background-size: 100%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.article_pagination2 .back_arrow2.arrow-disable {
  background: url(http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/dainikbhaskar2010/images/pagination/ie_back_page_aro_2_disable.png) no-repeat #fff;
}
.article_pagination2 .next_arrow2 {
  background: url(http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/dainikbhaskar2010/images/pagination/ie_next_page_aro_2.png) no-repeat #fff;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  float: right;
  overflow: visible;
  margin-left: 5px;
  background-size: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.article_pagination2 .next_arrow2.arrow-disable {
  background: url(http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/dainikbhaskar2010/images/pagination/ie_next_page_aro_2_disable.png) no-repeat #fff;
}
.article_pagination2 .arrow-disable a {
  cursor: default;
}
.article_pagination2 .next_arrow2 strong,
.article_pagination2 .back_arrow2 strong {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  font-size: 12px;
  left: 3px
}
.article_pagination2 .arrow-disable strong {
  color: #aeaeae;
}
.slideContainer.slide-row {
  height: 62px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slideContainer vidopia slide-row">
  <style>
  </style>
  <div class="article_pagination2">
    <div class="back_arrow2 arrow-disable"><a title="Prev" href="javascript:void(0);"><strong>Prev</strong></a>
    </div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div onclick="location.href='http://www0.bhaskar.com/news-ht/SPO-IPL-OFIPL-introducing-all-the-teams-of-indian-premier-league-8-4957058-PHO.html?seq=1'" class="pagination_no2"><span title="Slide 1" class="pg_number2 active">1</span>
          <figure class="article_image2"><span class="image_inner"><img src="http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/thumbnail/70x70/web2images/www.bhaskar.com/2015/04/07/players_1428406480.jpg"></span>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div onclick="location.href='http://www0.bhaskar.com/news-ht/SPO-IPL-OFIPL-introducing-all-the-teams-of-indian-premier-league-8-4957058-PHO.html?seq=2'" class="pagination_no2"><span title="Slide 2" class="pg_number2 ">2</span>
          <figure class="article_image2"><span class="image_inner"><img src="http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/thumbnail/70x70/web2images/www.bhaskar.com/2015/04/07/dhoni_1428406477.jpg"></span>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div onclick="location.href='http://www0.bhaskar.com/news-ht/SPO-IPL-OFIPL-introducing-all-the-teams-of-indian-premier-league-8-4957058-PHO.html?seq=3'" class="pagination_no2"><span title="Slide 3" class="pg_number2 ">3</span>
          <figure class="article_image2"><span class="image_inner"><img src="http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/thumbnail/70x70/web2images/www.bhaskar.com/2015/04/07/bailey_1428406477.jpg"></span>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div onclick="location.href='http://www0.bhaskar.com/news-ht/SPO-IPL-OFIPL-introducing-all-the-teams-of-indian-premier-league-8-4957058-PHO.html?seq=4'" class="pagination_no2"><span title="Slide 4" class="pg_number2 ">4</span>
          <figure class="article_image2"><span class="image_inner"><img src="http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/thumbnail/70x70/web2images/www.bhaskar.com/2015/04/07/gautam_1428406478.jpg"></span>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div onclick="location.href='http://www0.bhaskar.com/news-ht/SPO-IPL-OFIPL-introducing-all-the-teams-of-indian-premier-league-8-4957058-PHO.html?seq=5'" class="pagination_no2"><span title="Slide 5" class="pg_number2 ">5</span>
          <figure class="article_image2"><span class="image_inner"><img src="http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/thumbnail/70x70/web2images/www.bhaskar.com/2015/04/07/rohit-1_1428406482.jpg"></span>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div onclick="location.href='http://www0.bhaskar.com/news-ht/SPO-IPL-OFIPL-introducing-all-the-teams-of-indian-premier-league-8-4957058-PHO.html?seq=6'" class="pagination_no2"><span title="Slide 6" class="pg_number2 ">6</span>
          <figure class="article_image2"><span class="image_inner"><img src="http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/thumbnail/70x70/web2images/www.bhaskar.com/2015/04/07/watson_1428406488.jpg"></span>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div onclick="location.href='http://www0.bhaskar.com/news-ht/SPO-IPL-OFIPL-introducing-all-the-teams-of-indian-premier-league-8-4957058-PHO.html?seq=7'" class="pagination_no2"><span title="Slide 7" class="pg_number2 ">7</span>
          <figure class="article_image2"><span class="image_inner"><img src="http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/thumbnail/70x70/web2images/www.bhaskar.com/2015/04/07/virat-1_1428406484.jpg"></span>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div onclick="location.href='http://www0.bhaskar.com/news-ht/SPO-IPL-OFIPL-introducing-all-the-teams-of-indian-premier-league-8-4957058-PHO.html?seq=8'" class="pagination_no2"><span title="Slide 8" class="pg_number2 ">8</span>
          <figure class="article_image2"><span class="image_inner"><img src="http://i9.dainikbhaskar.com/thumbnail/70x70/web2images/www.bhaskar.com/2015/04/07/warner_1428406486.jpg"></span>
          </figure>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="next_arrow2 "><a title="Next" href="http://www0.bhaskar.com/news-ht/SPO-IPL-OFIPL-introducing-all-the-teams-of-indian-premier-league-8-4957058-PHO.html?seq=2"><strong>Next</strong></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/2j795bvm/

Comment: : Thanks for the perfect answer, but can you explain how the pseudo element is helping here...

Comment: No problem. The pseudo element is used purely for the vertical alignment. The `img` is `inline` so will vertical align with other `inline` content in the containing `span`. By adding a pseudo element with `display: inline-block;` we can make it fit the full height of the `span`. As the pseudo element is `inline` the `img` will be vertically aligned to the middle of it.